# Zoom Out the Location in MapView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Im Having **MapView** In which I added some 5 Annotations in the Areas of Chennai.. I want to Zoom Out the Chennai as soon as the MapView Begins Loading so that Annotations will be Visible Clearly.
In viewDidLoad:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location6;
    location6.latitude=12.9758;
    location6.longitude=80.2205;
    MapAnnotation *ann6=[[MapAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:@"Chennai-Velacherry" andCoordinate:location6];
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann6];

     CLLocationCoordinate2D centerlocation;
    centerlocation.longitude=13.0810;
    centerlocation.longitude=80.2740;


    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerlocation animated:NO];
     [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Comment: may be you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523604/zoom-to-fit-region-for-all-annotations-ending-up-zooming-in-between-annotation use the method -(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapView

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I zoom an MKMapView to the users current location without CLLocationManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473706/how-do-i-zoom-an-mkmapview-to-the-users-current-location-without-cllocationmanag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this,

```
        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
        region.center.latitude = [currentPlace.latitude doubleValue];
        region.center.longitude = [currentPlace.longitude doubleValue];
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.03f; 
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.03f;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
        [mapView setDelegate:self];
        mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
        mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

these will vary your zoom level,

```
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.03f; 
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.03f;
```

Comment: Im having Coordinates in CLLocationCoordinate.. I am unable to pass the value to Region.center.latitude

Comment: actually im getting out of the area

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16354/discussion-between-venkat-and-vanitha)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a predefined set of zoom levels. Instead, you can set the visible area of a `MKMapView` using `MKCoordinateRegion`. Sample code available [here](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/).

Comment: I tried this But getting an Error as.. No visible@interface for ViewController declares the Selector setRegion animated:NO.. How to over this Error

Comment: Is the map zoom in/out while pinching?

Comment: No the code is not running Instead Getting the Above specified Error

Comment: Actually your code look correct - all you have to do is probably clean the project and possibly restart XCode.

Comment: Check whether you have included '@class yourViewController;' in ViewController.h above '@interface'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

Create a function like :

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mv {

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;

topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;

topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

for(MKAnnotations* annotation in mv.annotations)
{
   topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
   topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

   bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
   bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides

region = [mv regionThatFits:region];
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

And call this function in viewDidLoad after all the pins are plotted

Comment: I dont understand the logic behind this code.. Sorry Im a Begineer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#define kMAPSPAN 1600

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 1*kMAPSPAN, 1*kMAPSPAN);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

mapView is your MKMapView object and kMAPSPAN can be set according to your need and zoomLocation is your coordinate2D location for chennai

Comment: Im getting The ocean area as a zoomed position .. What number i can set to get the Accurate

Comment: it depends on how accurately you provide your coordinate2D location. assign zoomLocation with the coordinate(latitude longitude) of Chennai(which is you want to zoom)

Comment: I provided The Accurate Value .. Still i dont get .. Can u tell me?

Comment: did you provide zoomLocation.latitude=your_latitude and zoomLocation.longitude=your_longitude? Hope you didn't make this mistake zoomLocation.longitude=your_latitude zoomLocation.latitude=your_longitude.

Comment: Here is My code:
     CLLocationCoordinate2D centerlocation;
    centerlocation.longitude=13.0810;
    centerlocation.longitude=80.2740;
    
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerlocation, 1*kMAPSPAN, 1*kMAPSPAN);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

Comment: you are doing the mistake i mentioned above... 13.0810 is latitude not longitude and similar for longitude

Comment: Extremely sorry I was forced to Edit Often.. By Mistake i did .. Really Sorry

Comment: use this mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;